# unable to plot histogram(hist2d)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to plot length of objects vs total count of objects using hist2d. I am getting the following error. Can you please help me in finding the error.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

```
count=799.000000

plt.hist2d(length,count,bins = 10)

plt.xlabel('count')
plt.ylabel('length')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
print(length)
1      3.978235
2      4.740024
3      3.470375
4      3.978235
5      3.808948
         ...   
807    5.078597
808    4.655381
809    4.232164
810    4.655381
811    3.470375
Name: length_mm, Length: 799, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Could you please include a snippet of length_grain, so one can reproduce your issue?

Comment: sorry my bad . Its length vs count which i am trying to plot.I have edited my question

Comment: Are you sure you want to use hist2d and not just the regular histogram? Where are the x and y values for the chart (length is x, but what's y?)

Comment: X is length in milimeter and Y is number of samples  which is 799.So should I create an array of numbers for Y (0 to 800 ) and then plot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue in you code is the use of `hist2d` rather than the good-old `hist`. With `hist`, you don't have to pass the number of items - it gets that from the Series:

```
plt.hist(length, bins = 10)
plt.xlabel('count')
plt.ylabel('length')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

The result (for a small amount of data) is:

[image]

If, on the other hand, you'd looking for a bar chart, here's the way to do it for `length`:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(length.index, length)
fig.show()
```

The result (for limited data, of course)  is:

[image]

Comment: Not really. You don't need count. the 'hist' function takes care of it on its own.

Comment: but i need count in X axis that should be whole number right and Y axis should be the length. I am not getting results like that

Comment: in the original question, you had one series of numbers - 'length'. My understanding was that you'd like to create a histogram of this series. Isn't that the case?

Comment: when i find the len(length) it says 799.when I am printing length i am getting two columns .I need to plot the floating point values vs total number of items.Y axis should contain floating point values and X axis the count . I am little confused here .Is this the right approach ?

Comment: Isn't one column just a series of numbers, from 1 to 800 or so? Maybe the right question - do you have an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I dont have it and I am trying to plot .I need to have X to have values from range 1 to 800 and Y should be their corresponding height in floating values . Is there any way you can help me with this .When i print length i am getting two columns .Is there a way i can extract all the floating point values into array.Then I can use hist2d.Thank you very much for your patience and time

Comment: Are you looking for a graph that looks more or less like that: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdatavizproject.com%2Fdata-type%2Fline-chart%2F&psig=AOvVaw3BZgjxSBHKVNXWobwlRhpM&ust=1592982197556000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLi1lqKvl-oCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAN ?

Comment: I need a histogram .Like this .https://datavizproject.com/data-type/histogram/

Comment: When plotting a histogram, you split your data into multiple bins, according to their value (3.978235, 4.740024, etc, in your example). The x-axis is than the different bin. The y axis is not the value of the points - but rather how many items you have in that bin. Are you 100% certain you're looking for a histogram and not for a bar chart?

Comment: In any case, if you'll upload the source data to somewhere, I'd be glad to create a couple of charts.

Comment: Can you pls help me with bar chart ?But for bar chart we need length values in one array and count in another array right .I extracted length from an array now when I am printing I am getting two different columns.Also length is only till 799 but there are values even for 811 .I am confused regarding this

Comment: What do you see when you print type(length) ?

Comment: https://snipboard.io/uVEJik.jpg

https://snipboard.io/UR6nsh.jpg


https://snipboard.io/8dIrSW.jpg

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> when i print type(length) and in screenshot i have share example of height similar to lenght

Comment: Now I got X values correct but Y values are wrong it should be length.Pls see my attached screenshot 
https://snipboard.io/nNrFMk.jpg

Comment: Should I set a range for Y values and then plot ?

Comment: No need. Just take length, which is a series, and plot the values of the series against its index. As in my code above.